# GCC : "definition of BLAH is not in namespace enclosing"

Tags: c++, namespaces

I'm trying to figure out something in VCVRack.

In Template.hpp

```
using namespace rack;
...
struct SlowSliderWidget : public OpaqueWidget {
    void draw(NVGcontext *vg) override;
};
```

then in MyWidget.cpp

```
#include "Template.hpp"

namespace rack {

void SlowSliderWidget::draw(NVGcontext *vg) {
    nvgBeginPath(vg);
    nvgRect(vg, 0, 0, 100, 100);
    nvgFill(vg);
}

} // namespace rack
```

This gives me the following compiler error :

```
g++  -Wsuggest-override -std=c++11  -DSLUG=Template -fPIC -I../../include -I../../dep/include -DVERSION=0.6.0 -MMD -MP -g -O3 -march=nocona -ffast-math -fno-finite-math-only -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -DARCH_LIN -c -o build/src/MyWidget.cpp.o src/MyWidget.cpp
src/MyWidget.cpp:6:43: error: definition of ‘void SlowSliderWidget::draw(NVGcontext*)’ is not in namespace enclosing ‘SlowSliderWidget’ [-fpermissive]
 void SlowSliderWidget::draw(NVGcontext *vg) {
                                           ^
../../compile.mk:64: recipe for target 'build/src/MyWidget.cpp.o' failed
```

Now, searching around I find various complaints about this type of error in GCC.

But all of them seem to be about attempts to redefine the meaning of the same class name in the same namespace.

But if I understand my C++ here, I am NOT trying to redefine the name. I declare the name SlowSliderWidget and the SlowSliderWidget::draw in the Template.hpp file and I simply try to define the function body of draw in the MyWidget.cpp file.

So why am I getting an error message? The wording seems to imply I'm not in the same namespace. But in both files I am in namespace rack. Aren't I?

Comment: `SlowSliderWidget` isn't declared inside the `rack` namespace.  Why are you trying to define its functions in there?

Comment: Isn't that what the "using namespace rack" does in the first line of the Template.hpp file does?

Comment: No, that says you are using stuff from the namespace, not that you are putting it in the namespace.  You put things in a namespace like you did for your definition.

Comment: Ah, OK. Thanks. That's my answer then. I'm very rusty on C++.